# Suricata to monitor entire network

Tags: monitoring, suricata

How to configure Suricate to capture packets on the entire network? I have already configured the Suricate but it's only capturing packets that send to Suricata installed host. I want the whole network packets to be captured by Suricata.

I have two different networks such as Data and Internal where Suricata is placed in Internal Network. I have already configured my switch to monitor few ports and destine to second port of Suricata Server but still I didn't see any changes.

Can some help on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the interface should be in promiscuous mode - to see all traffic.

(HOWTO depends on your os)

> ifconfig eth1 up
>
> ifconfig eth1 promisc

and check what is defined in **suricata yaml** who's under $HOME_NET , and what rules files are set, I recommend to take a glance there to better understand why certain rule is fired.

Comment: Let me try on promisc mode